# MVC3 how to create URLs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, url

I see people using Html.ActionLink() and Url.RouteUrl() etc. etc.
But surely this will lead to a maintenance nightmare if routes need to be redesigned?

How are people organising the generation of URLs in a typesafe and manageable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [T4MVC](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC) to generate typesafe checks at compile time for your MVC urls.

T4MVC analyses your Controller classes, and generates code that will generate typesafe url's.

Instead of

```
@Html.ActionLink("New customer", "Create", new { Controller = "Customer", orgID = orgID })
```

You can use code like:

```
@Html.ActionLink("New customer", MVC.Customer.Create(orgID))
```

Comment: workable solution - but ... this "MVC3" creates way more problems than it solves ... better to uninstall MVC3 and write HttpHandlers.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly typed URL generation via lambda expressions was available for a period of time during the MVC 1.0 beta timeframe. It was removed since the MVC architecture does not actually have a 1-to-1 mapping between action names and controller method names. See this [Phil Haack blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/08/29/how-a-method-becomes-an-action.aspx) for details.

It is of course still possible to do it, and assuming you're not using action names that differ from method names, it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a action you use the `Html.ActionLink()`. This will create a `<a href="..." ></a>` hyperlink to chosen action.

If you want to create a url and use it not for a hyperlink, you can use the `Url.Content()` or the `Url.RouteUrl()`. The content accepts a string and gerenates a safe url. The Route url takes a route object.